# Garage key frequency and baud rate

Tags: rf

1) What means baud rate in garage door keys? Is it a waiting period between each byte sent? (I am talking about OOK keys). And can i just sent all the byes without wait?

2) What all baud rates are used in garage door keys (with fixed codes) and which ones are the most common?

3)What are ALL the frequencies used in garage doors (whole world)?

Comment: This is a bad question and I don't forsee any good coming from the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Garage door openers don't use standard serial communication so the baud rate is not very meaningful.

Typically they will use some sort of delay modulation with long and short pulses at a few hundred bits per second.

They are also not necessarily byte oriented - it is up the individual manufacturer.

In the US any frequency between 270MHZ and 450MHz can be used but 315Mz and 390Mz are common.

The rest of the world tends to use 418Mhz and 433MHz and they are becoming more common in the US.

Comment: I am talking about garage keys with fixed codes that have 8-12 bits of data. They used Dip Switches (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIP_switch) to choose which code it will send. How do these then send a few 100 bits PER SECOND if their code has maximum 12 bits? And I am asking what delay is used between each sent bit......

Comment: That's the rate of communication.  As you say each burst of communication may only be a couple of dozen bits but that is then repeated multiple times.  Also don't forget there is a fairly lengthy preamble that sends a number roof bits before the actual data.